# Is it possible to find out server response time and client rendering time using Fiddler?

Tags: telerik, performance-testing, fiddler, response-time, server-response

Hope you are fine, I rarely use Fiddler for my web calls. Now I have tuned some queries in my application. So I would like to test my server response time and client rendering time using Fiddler. Is that option available in Fiddler? If yes, can someone help with that? I have already gone through this [link](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-traffic-recording), that couldn't help. Thanks in advance.

Update:

If fiddler doesn't do this, can we do this with the help of IE browser console or any extensions?

NB: My application works only in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, fiddler is not able to capture the rendering time or anything that is done purely on the client side. It is only able to eavesdrop on the data sent back and forth between the client and the server.

If you want to do some testing for performance from the client-side standpoint. You ahould take a loom at [Chrome dev tools `timeline` feature](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool)

Comment: Thanks for the information. But my application works only in IE. Can we do this using IE dev tools?

Comment: Any specific IE version?

Comment: Sure, as of IE11 Microsoft has revamped their developer tools. To access it simply type `F12` with a browser window open.

You can take a look at the docs both for IE11(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx)  and Edge(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/)

It provides separate tools for debugging `Network`, `UI Responsiveness` and JS execution (named `Profiler`).

Comment: The network provides more or less the same functionality you already can debug with Fiddler.

`UI Responsiveness` provides profiling from the UI standpoint and I feel it fits best what you are trying to accomplish.

`Profiler` takes a look from the JS point of view. So it measures stats based on JS execution.

Both tools need to be explicitly started/stopped to gather and present data. You can do this simply by navigating to the tag and clicking the green "play" button.

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed information. I am accepting it as answer :)